# Linq find min value of each object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects with the following properties

```
public class Client
{
Id Guid,
FromDate datetime
}
```

List of Clients

```
  List<Clients> clients = new List<Clients>();
```

There are many of the same Ids in this list with different FromDates. How can I get a list of the Id and the min FromDate for each Id?

So for example:

```
Id    FromDate
1       2015-01-01
1       2016-01-01
2       2015-02-02
2       2015-12-31
```

I want to end up with a list with the following:

```
Id    FromDate
1       2015-01-01
2       2015-02-02
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a [`group by`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query=clients.GroupBy(c=>c.Id)
                 .Select(g=>new {Id=g.Key, FromDate=g.Min(c=>c.FromDate)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clients.GroupBy(client => client.Id, client => client)
                .Select(times => times.OrderBy(client => client.FromDate).First())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways two of them are

- `Distinct`
     You have to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<Client>` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)
     and than you can call:

  ```
  IEnumerable<Client> noduplicates = products.Distinct(new ClientComparer());
  ```
- `GroupBy`

  ```
  var result = clients
                  .GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                  .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, FromDate = g.Min(c => c.FromDate) });

  var result = from c in clients
      group c by new { id = c.Id } into g
      select new { id = g.Key, FromDate = g.Min(c => c.FromDate) };
  ```